Does the shade of color (light vs dark) in a trademark matter?
With respect to a U.S. Registration, for a trademark that claims the color green, does the shade of green make a difference?  For example, if the registered mark is in dark green and I submit a specimen of use which shows the mark in light green, would that be accepted?

Did you know that some trademarks are for very specific shades ? Like the blue of Tiffany boxes.

Or the Various shades of black


With respect to a U.S. Registration, for a trademark that claims the
color green, does the shade of green make a difference?

Usually it would, and usually the specificity expected would be much greater than light green v. dark green.

For example, if the registered mark is in dark green and I submit a
specimen of use which shows the mark in light green, would that be
accepted?

There are several things that could happen depending upon how the PTO handles you application. The most likely possibility is that the Patent and Trademark Office would either reject your specimen, or require you to amend your trademark application, so that the two conform to each other.

Yes, typically you will have to specify an exact shade of green - there are various systems of colour specification.

And yet sometimes, any old green will do, such as for golf's Masters Green Jacket, recently trademarked: https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=88310303&caseSearchType=US_APPLICATION&caseType=DEFAULT&searchType=statusSearch

And don't use John Deere green and yellow on farm equipment: https://www.farm-equipment.com/articles/14710-deere-wins-trademark-lawsuit-in-protection-of-green-and-yellow-colors

Or the same green and red, that's Fendt.

The hexcode of colors is not trademarkable but the name of the color is.
The New South Wales Waratahs play in a kit color similar to Manchester City but as long as they don't advertise the color of there rugby jerseys as Manchester blue they should be ok.

I don't believe this is accurate, at least in the USA. See, e.g., SN 76408109 (UPS's mark of the color approximating Pantone 462C), Qualitex Co. v. Jacobson Products Co., 514 U.S. 159 (1995).
